# Parallel processing for counting polymorphic SNPs in paired line comparisons

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the number of polymorphic snps between pairs of lines, and I am running into a problem with the computational resources required to answer the question.  I know conceptually that the question can (and should) be answered using parallel processing, but I am struggling to figure out how to program the question for parallel processing.  I have not found a parallel processing question like this one.  Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Basically, I am trying to compare SNPs between pairs of lines: line 1 to lines 2, 3...7; then line 2 to lines 3,4...7. So n(n-1)/2 comparisons. For each SNP, if the two lines being compared match for AA, AB, or BB then lines are not polymorphic for that SNP.  If either line at a SNP has an 'NC' then the SNP is taken out of the calculation. So comparing lines 1 and 2: there is 1 matching SNP, 2 "NC SNPs", and 2 polymorphic SNPs (2 = 5-(1+2)).

I tried making the for loop faster using foreach, but I must have done something wrong as the result took even more time to complete.

I also tried writing the code as a function, and then calling the function which improved the speed marginally.

This is a toy data set of 7 lines and 5 SNPs, but in reality, the data set is 1000's of SNPs and hundreds of lines.

```
Line    SNP1    SNP2    SNP3    SNP4    SNP5
Line1   AA  BB  AA  NC  BB
Line2   AA  AA  NC  NC  AA
Line3   BB  AB  NC  BB  AA
Line4   NC  BB  AB  NC  BB
Line5   AA  AA  BB  AB  AA
Line6   NC  NC  AA  AA  NC
Line7   BB  AA  AA  NC  BB
```

code so far with help from a colleague

```
#load in the snps
snps <-read.csv("data.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)

#create all combinations first
#this is a built-in function that will spit out every combination. Just give it the line names twice.
#remove combinations with matching lines
test <- expand.grid(lineA = snps$Line, lineB = snps$Line) 
test <- test[which(test$lineA!=test$lineB),] 
test <- test[order(test$lineA),]
test <- test[!duplicated(t(apply(test, 1, sort))),]

#create empty columns to be populated
test["NC"]          <- NA
test["match"]       <- NA
test["polymorphic"] <- NA

#get the total number of snps so we can count polymorphic loci for each combo
snp_total_count <- ncol(snps)-1

for (i in 1:nrow(test))   
{
  #get the lines you are going to compare
  lineA <- which(snps$Line==test$lineA[i])
  lineB <- which(snps$Line==test$lineB[i])

  #find the matches not counting NC's 
  test$match[i] <- length(which(snps[lineA,]!="NC" & snps[lineA,]==snps[lineB,]))

  #find the NCs/- cases so paired NC's or single NC's. can't tell polymorphic state or not. count all together 
  #1st count positions in which both lineA and lineB are NC, 
  #then count positions in which only lineA is "NC" (lineA = NC and does not equal LineB) and 
  #then count positions in which only lineB is "NC"(lineB = NC and does not equal LineA) 
  #then add all 3 values together
  test$NC[i] <- length(which(snps[lineA,]=="NC" & snps[lineA,]==snps[lineB,])) + length(which(snps[lineA,]=="NC" & snps[lineA,]!=snps[lineB,])) + length(which(snps[lineB,]=="NC" & snps[lineA,]!=snps[lineB,]))

  #calculate # polymorphic SNPs = total - matching - NC snps 
  test$polymorphic[i] <- snp_total_count - (test$NC[i]+ test$match[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get matching SNPs use: `data[LineX, ] == d[LineY, ]`, to get `NC` SNPs use: `data[LineX, ] == "NC" | data[LineY, ] == "NC"`. And to run it in parallel you can use `future` which provides support for foreach parallelization.

```
library(doFuture)
registerDoFuture()
plan(multiprocess)

N <- nrow(d)
d$Line <- NULL

result <- foreach(i = 1:(N - 1), .combine = rbind) %do% {
    foreach(j = (i + 1):N, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
        data.frame(
            NC = sum(d[i, ] == "NC" | d[j, ] == "NC"),
            MATCH = sum(d[i, ] == d[j, ] & d[i, ] != "NC"),
            I = i, J = j)
    }
}
```

Data(`d`):

```
structure(list(Line = c("Line1", "Line2", "Line3", "Line4", "Line5", 
"Line6", "Line7"), SNP1 = c("AA", "AA", "BB", "NC", "AA", "NC", 
"BB"), SNP2 = c("BB", "AA", "AB", "BB", "AA", "NC", "AA"), SNP3 = c("AA", 
"NC", "NC", "AB", "BB", "AA", "AA"), SNP4 = c("NC", "NC", "BB", 
"NC", "AB", "AA", "NC"), SNP5 = c("BB", "AA", "AA", "BB", "AA", 
"NC", "BB")), .Names = c("Line", "SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3", "SNP4", 
"SNP5"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Result(`result`):

```
   NC MATCH I J
1   2     1 1 2
2   2     0 1 3
3   2     2 1 4
4   1     1 1 5
5   4     1 1 6
6   1     2 1 7
7   2     1 2 3
8   3     0 2 4
9   2     3 2 5
10  5     0 2 6
...
```

Comment: I found that I could get a faster result if I used: 'library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(doMC)
registerDoParallel(cores = (detectCores() - 1))
registerDoMC'

Comment: @Rquestion It's possible. Depends of every machine and how many cores your have. `future` might not use full capacity.

Comment: @Rquestion just curious. How big is your SNP data and how fast can you compute it?

Comment: I was testing the speed on a small trial set of up to 500 lines by 10 SNPs. full size data set: ~6K SNPs by ~1300 lines. it is currently running it on a super computer, so I don't know how long it will take. A colleague suggested matrix algebra might be a faster way to solve the problem, so I'm going to try that too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably get significant speed increases with `data.table` and  multiple cores if possible with `foreach` + `doMC`. Below is a simplistic example, you'd need to add in your specific conditions for what do with with NC values. Set the cores within `registerDoMC` to however many cores you have available.

```
library(data.table)
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=4)

dt <- data.table(Line=paste("Line", 1:100, sep=""), 
                SNP1=sample(c("AA", "AB", "AC", "BB", "BC", "CC"), size=100, replace=TRUE),
                SNP2=sample(c("AA", "AB", "AC", "BB", "BC", "CC"), size=100, replace=TRUE),
                SNP3=sample(c("AA", "AB", "AC", "BB", "BC", "CC"), size=100, replace=TRUE),
                SNP4=sample(c("AA", "AB", "AC", "BB", "BC", "CC"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
                )
```

looking at `head(dt)`:

```
    Line SNP1 SNP2 SNP3 SNP4
1: Line1   AC   BC   AB   AB
2: Line2   BC   BB   AA   AC
3: Line3   AB   BB   AA   AC
4: Line4   BC   BC   AC   BC
5: Line5   AB   AA   BB   AA
6: Line6   AB   AB   CC   AC
```

And going forward...

```
snpCols <- colnames(dt)[2:length(colnames(dt))]

results <- foreach(index.1 = 1:dim(dt)[1], .combine="rbind") %dopar% {
                row1 <- dt[index.1]
                foreach(index.2 = index.1:dim(dt)[1], .combine="rbind") %do% {
                    row2 <- dt[index.2]
                    # do operations / return final data.table object that has values containing column values you want
                    return(data.table("lineX"=row1$Line, 
                                      "lineY"=row2$Line,
                                      "nMatches"=sum(row1[,snpCols, with=FALSE] == row2[,snpCols, with=FALSE])
                                      )
                          )
    }
}
```

which yields the object `results`

```
        lineX   lineY nMatches
   1:   Line1   Line1        4
   2:   Line1   Line2        0
   3:   Line1   Line3        0
   4:   Line1   Line4        1
   5:   Line1   Line5        0
  ---
5046:  Line98  Line99        0
5047:  Line98 Line100        0
5048:  Line99  Line99        4
5049:  Line99 Line100        0
5050: Line100 Line100        4
```

Note that this is also comparing each line to itself; you could either keep or remove those depending on what you need from this point on.